# I want to read URL parameters of Parent frame and use it in page which is embedded in iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I am working on one react page which is embedded in iframe on clients website. I want to read GLCID from their website url and use it in my react page. Is there any way to do this?